# sas macro loop to rename variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Hi I am trying to rename variables using SAS Macro loop.

```
%Let t1=12Mth;
%Let t2=20;
%Let t3=30;
%Let t4=40;
%Let t5=50;
%Let t6=60;

%macro Re(time);
%Do I = 1 %to &time.; 
data MilkNew;
set Milk;
rename MT&&t&I..Sp=MTSp&&t&I.;
run;
%end;
%mend Re;
%Re(6)
```

This loop is mean to rename MT...Sp to MTSp.... Eg:MT20SP to MTSp20.
When I run my loop, there was no error but the variable names were not changed in MilkNew at all.
Where does the problem come? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have seen the *last* variable name in the loop (so the 6th) changed.  That's because you repeated the same data step with the same source dataset but a *different* destination - so each time you 'forgot' the changes made in the earlier step.

So, this would've worked, though I'll get in a minute to why this isn't a good way to do this.

```
%Let t1=12Mth;
%Let t2=20;
%Let t3=30;
%Let t4=40;
%Let t5=50;
%Let t6=60;

%macro Re(time);
%Do I = 1 %to &time.; 
data Milk;
set Milk;
rename MT&&t&I..Sp=MTSp&&t&I.;
run;
%end;
%mend Re;

data milk;
  input 
    MT12mthSP
    MT20SP
    MT30SP
    MT40SP
    MT50SP
    MT60SP
  ;
  datalines;
12 20 30 40 50 60
;;;;
run;


%Re(6)
```

Here I had it make all changes to `Milk` and save them back in that dataset.  If you want to preserve `Milk` then first make `Milk_New` then have that in both `set` and `data` statements.

---

Second, you should not do a new data step for each change. Macros don't have to have a data step in them; they can be run inside the datastep.

So for example:

```
%macro Re(time);
  %Do I = 1 %to &time.; 
  rename MT&&t&I..Sp=MTSp&&t&I.;
  %end;
%mend Re;
data milk_new;
  set milk;
  %Re(6);
run;
```

Even better would be generating this list outside of a macro entirely - look up "generating code SAS" for suggestions on that.

---

If you didn't see any renames *at all*, you also may have an issue where a label is present on the column(s).  That won't affect your usage of the variable name, but it will make it confusing.  Use

```
label _all_;
```

Or include a label-clearing statement (`label <varname>;` where you pop in the same variable name as the *original* variable name before rename) inside your macro loop to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer!

Answer (score 2):

If the only purpose of the macro is to rename the variables in the data set, then why read the data with a `set` statement. Your data set is probably really small so you don't even realize the inefficiency of doing that. Instead use the `modify` statement in `proc datasets` to accomplish the same thing, but more efficiently. Here's an alternative macro for you.

```
%macro renamevar(dsname, time);
%local lib ds i; 
%let lib = %sysfunc(coalescec(%scan(&dsname, -2, %str(.)), work));
%let ds = %scan(&dsname, -1, %str(.));

proc datasets lib=&lib nolist;
modify &ds;
    rename
        %do i = 1 %to &time; 
            mt&&t&i..Sp=MTSp&&t&i.
        %end;
        ;
quit;
%mend;

%renamevar(milk, 6);
```

Here's the log after the macro call:

```
NOTE: Renaming variable mt12MthSp to MTSp12Mth.
NOTE: Renaming variable mt20Sp to MTSp20.
NOTE: Renaming variable mt30Sp to MTSp30.
NOTE: Renaming variable mt40Sp to MTSp40.
NOTE: Renaming variable mt50Sp to MTSp50.
NOTE: Renaming variable mt60Sp to MTSp60.

NOTE: MODIFY was successful for WORK.MILK.DATA.
NOTE: PROCEDURE DATASETS used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion. I didn't notice the efficiency problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the loop so that it only generates just the RENAME statement (or even just the old=new name pairs).  What is happening now is that you keep overwriting MilkNew so only the last RENAME has any effect.

```
%macro Re(time);
 data MilkNew;
   set Milk;
 %do I = 1 %to &time.; 
   rename MT&&t&I..Sp=MTSp&&t&I.;
 %end;
 run;
%mend Re;
%Re(6)
```